# Sending JSON array of strings using Jersey

Tags: java, jquery, json, jersey

I am trying to send JSON array of string and perform some task on serverside. 
Here is my JS:

```
var x = ["Salam","Saghol","11"]

$.ajax({
url: '../rest/group/addusers',
type: 'POST',
data: JSON.stringify(x),
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: 'json',
async: false,
success: function(msg) {
    alert(msg);
}
});
```

And my Java method:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/addusers")
public Response addUsersToGroup(List<String> users) {
    System.out.println(users);
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Salam").build();
}
```

When I send the request I get "415 (Unsupported Media Type)" error message.

Please help me just passing the array elements (Strings) to the method below.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Here are my headers:
[image]

Comment: What does your x look like, give us an example

Comment: Sorry, I added the x

Comment: Could you use firebug to check if the contentType header has indeed been set properly.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is that the JSON libraries have not been added to the project. Link on similar error : http://vitalflux.com/angularjs-springmvc-fix-415-unsupported-media-type-error/

Comment: The JSON library Jackson is included in project as I am using it on other class and it works. It might be it is missing some annotation, but which I cant figure out.

Comment: Anything in the server log?

Comment: Nothing in the server log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the **"users"** parameter can't be deserialized. While my idea might be clear, the logic is not correct enough programmatically.

Usually data from POST are extracted using query parameters (using "=","?","&" as separator). In my case I put the data directly to POST output stream. And getting all data in string representation is more logical.

So I changed the code into this:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/addusers")    
public Response addUsersToGroup(String users) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<String> l = mapper.readValue(users, List.class);

    for (String s : l) {
        System.out.println("Item: "+s);
    }


    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Salam").build();
}
```

And problem is solved. Thanks for attention.